# How to execute mysql shell code from python .py file?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-shell

I have found this sample for uploading csv file to mysql server which is faster -->

```
MySQL localhost osm JS > 
util.importTable("/usr/local/mysql/mysql-files/load_data.csv", 
{schema: "parallel", table: "parallel_load", columns:
["user_id","visible","name","size","latitude","longitude",
"timestamp","public","description","inserted"], 
dialect: "csv-unix", skipRows: 0, showProgress: true, 
fieldsOptionallyEnclosed: true, fieldsTerminatedBy: ",", 
linesTerminatedBy: "\n",fieldsEnclosedBy: '"',threads: 8, 
bytesPerChunk: "1G", maxRate: "2G"})
```

I want to execute this mysql shell command from .py file where I have function for upload data. How is this possible to run mysql shell command from python ? I have installed mysql shell in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\mysqlsh.exe .`
Thank you.

Comment: Look at module `subprocess`.